# Multiple table insert from ASP.net MVC page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to insert  the data into 'Order' , 'OrderDetails' tables at the same time. How can I get Auto generated OrderID from the Order table. I am using ADO.NET Entity model.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
var order = new Order();
//fill your properties here

var orderDetails = new OrderDetails();
//fill your properties here

orderDetails.Order = order;

db.AddToOrders(order);
db.AddToOrderDetails(orderDetails);

//Save changes
db.SaveChanges();
```

Hope it will help you with your problem.